# The content of element type "plant" must match (name,climate,height,usage,image)

Tags: xml, dtd

I am writing a DTD for the below xml code.However the output is

**The content of element type "plant" must match (name,climate,height,usage,image)**

Here is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "plantdtd.dtd">

<catalog>

<title>Flowers of the week</title>

<plant id="A1">

     <name>Aloe vera</name>

     <climate>tropical</climate>

     <height>60-100cm</height>

     <usage>medicinal</usage>

     <image>aloevera.jpg</image>

 </plant>

 <plant id="A2">

      <name>Orchidaceae</name>

      <height>8-12in</height>

      <usage>medicinal</usage>

      <usage>decoration</usage>

      <image>Orchidaceae.jpg</image>

 </plant>

 </catalog>
```

This is my DTD.

```
<?xml encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT catalog (title,plant+)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT plant (name,climate,height,usage,image)>
<!ATTLIST plant id CDATA  #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT climate (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT height (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT usage (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT image (#PCDATA)>
```

Please tell me whats wrong with the above DTD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the instance document is "right" and the DTD is "wrong", then you need to change the DTD to allow climate to be omitted (write `climate?`) and to allow usage to be repeated (write `usage+`). That will make these two example `plant` elements valid, but of course to design the DTD you need to consider all possible valid `plant` elements, not just these two.